# adding values to month columns based on date value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with user observations.

Each observation has an id, userID, signup month and cancel month. 
Each userID can have several entries (orders).

I want to create one column for each month, that is either set to 1 or 0, depending if the user is active or not. I want to have columns for 2017-01 until 2018-12

Example: userID 3 has signed up in 2018-03 and canceled in 2018-05. The columns 2018-03, 2018-04, and 2018-05 should have a value of 1 for this observation, all other columns should be 0.

Not sure how to do it in python in the most efficient way.

expected output

````py
id  userID  signupmonth  cancelmonth  tenure  2017-01  2017-02 ... 2018-03  2018-04  2018-05 2018-06 ... 2018-12
23  23434  2018-03       2018-05      3       0        0       ... 1        1   1    0       0       ... 0
24  23435  2017-01       2018-03      14      1        1       ... 1        0   0    0       0       ... 0```
````

Comment: Can you add some sample data, expected output, e.g for 2 users?

Comment: @jezrael here you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) in list comprehension for list of dictionaries for matched values, create DataFrame, replace missing values to `0` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
L = [dict.fromkeys(pd.period_range(s, e), 1) 
           for s, e in zip(df['signupmonth'], df['cancelmonth'])]

rng = pd.period_range('2017-01', '2018-12', freq='m')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index, columns=rng).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   2017-01  2017-02  2017-03  2017-04  2017-05  2017-06  2017-07  2017-08  \
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1   

   2017-09  2017-10  ...  2018-03  2018-04  2018-05  2018-06  2018-07  \
0        0        0  ...        1        1        1        0        0   
1        1        1  ...        1        0        0        0        0   

   2018-08  2018-09  2018-10  2018-11  2018-12  
0        0        0        0        0        0  
1        0        0        0        0        0  

[2 rows x 24 columns]

df = df.join(df1)
#print (df)
```